# Full documentation on YAML mapping for Doctrine ORM?

Tags: doctrine, entity-relationship, yaml, doctrine-orm

The [YAML mapping documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/yaml-mapping.html) for entities seems to be lacking.  It doesn't explain what the different types, the different generator strategies, what mappedBy means, what types of cascade values are allowed, how to define a many-to-one relationship, and a whole lot more.  Where can I find full documentation for this YAML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have look at **Doctrine\Orm\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo** class located at

```
path/to/doctrine/library/Orm/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php
```

In this class you can find mostly what's possible. If you read the comments carefully it will give you a better idea.

Comment: the Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver is a better class to look at

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the yaml format documentation for doctrine 2 is pretty limited at the moment.

Right now, the best way to figure out the yaml format is to look at the yaml driver implemetation.

**Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver**

Read through the the implementation of the `loadMetadataForClass` method. That shows you what properties the driver is expecting where.

You can also look at the [annotations documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html) to supplement your understanding. Many of the documented field names and expected values are the same as the yaml format. For example: once you figure out `@column` corresponds to the `fields` element of the yaml format, the rest of the annotations documentation for that element lines up with the yaml format.

Comment: Haven't used Symfony in awhile, but thanks for sharing for anyone else who encounters this question! :)

Answer (score 0):

The [v1.2 manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/yaml-schema-files/en) is much more complete.

Comment: But the YAML structure changed in 2.0.